# attempted import error: 'Map' is not exported from 'react-leaflet' (imported as 'LeafletMap')

Tags: react-leaflet

I wanted to render map in react js for my project. SO for it i installed `react-leaflet` using code `npm i react-leaflet` and also did `npm i leaflet` in terminal and entered some code for react leaflet.
The code is given Below:

```
import React from "react";
import { Map as LeafletMap, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
import "./map.css";
// import { showDataOnMap } from "./util";

function Map({ countries, casesType, center, zoom }) {
  return (
    <div className="map">
      <LeafletMap center={center} zoom={zoom}>
        <TileLayer
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        />
      </LeafletMap>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Map;
```

but the problem is it shows error

Failed to compile
./src/Map.js
Attempted import error: '`Map`' is not exported from '`react-leaflet`' (imported as '`LeafletMap`').
This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.

**what is the problem with my code please can anyone help me?**

Comment: which `react-leaflet` version are you using?

Comment: I don't know about it Thank you very much for consideration and your kind reply  But It worked I had to Export MapContainer intead of Map only.      That is: import { MapContainer as LeafletMap} from "react-leaflet".

Answer (score 2):

Change:
`import { Map as LeafletMap, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";`
To:
`import { MapContainer as LeafletMap, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";`